# How to make a div layer ignore user clicks, and allow the click to pass to the div/select below?

Tags: html, css

[image]

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/ztIua

I have a custom styled select here with a svg dropdown arrow on top of it. However if you try to click on the arrow itself it does not open the select because of some sort of layered hierarchy. Is there anyway to disable that div from being clickable with just CSS?

```
<h2>
    <div class="drop_arrow"></div>
    <select id="getRoute">
        <option class="routeSelector">Onboarding</option>
        <option class="routeSelector">Engagement</option>
        <option class="routeSelector">Popular Searches</option>
        <option class="routeSelector">Unregistered</option>
    </select>
</h2>

#getRoute {
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 180px;
    font: 16px LatoBold;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.drop_arrow {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 10px;
    left: 150px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 12px;
    background-position: -520px 0px;
    background-size: 1600px 1600px;
    background-image: url(http://leongaban.com/images/dash.svg), none;
-moz-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -o-user-select: none; 
}
```

Comment: One does not simply ignore div layer's

Comment: I was trying to find some transparency type style, not sure I deserve a -1 on this one :/

Comment: i didnt downvote it, i actually think its a valid question, i am looking into it now.

Comment: Sorry yeah that part wasn't direct at you :) (just made my title a bit more specific incase that was it)

Comment: Found an answer! Needed some mental exercise before bed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the drop down list relative position (so that it is above the arrow in the stack order), and a transparent background (so the arrow is visible through the drop down):

```css
#getRoute {
    ...
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bcjgJ

Comment: Ah! That was what I was looking for :D I knew CSS could do it! thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe i have found a solution.

adding the JS:

```
function dropDown(){
  var dropdown = document.getElementById('getRoute');
    var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
    dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

and triggering this on the arrow click should do the trick .

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xiDmw

Comment: Oh sweet thanks! I thought there was a simple CSS trick, but yeah going with JS in the end :)

Comment: Ah @gilly3 found the CSS answer, but +1 still man for the help and research :)

Answer (score 1):

css is for display not for click events.

You need to use js to forward the click to the element you want

Comment: Good point, this just seems like too simple a solution to actually need JS for.

Comment: Ok right! sorry, I didn't try the code to understand what is wanted